# How to read and write to file at the same time in c#

Tags: c#, io, filestream

I need to use a file to make decision on binding my data. So originally I create a file contains value "NO". When first time the code read it, it will bind the data to a repeater to display, then change value in the file to "YES". When it run again (due to page reload), it read value "YES" which means data already binded, it will not bind the data again and change the file content to "NO" as original and finish running.

Here is what I tried:

```
// Use file to make binding data decision, 
//  avoid duplicate binding due to page reload:
using (var fileStream = 
    File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/binddecision.txt"), FileMode.Open))
{
    // read from the file
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        if (line == "NO")
        {
            companyRepeater.DataSource = companies1;
            companyRepeater.DataBind();

            LinkRepeater.DataSource = urls;
            LinkRepeater.DataBind();

            fileStream.SetLength(0); // truncate the file
            // If now is not record a loop yet, then write YES to the file
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("YES");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            streamReader.Close();
            // If now is a loop then write NO to the file
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it still shows error about stream using conflict. I read some methods on google but fail to implement it for this algorithm.

Could any one please help me?

Comment: Whats wrong with you or my post Chandra ?

Comment: just improved the formatting it took much space in the left side before I changed it

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is your effort deserved a thanks or a minus on my post ? Do it positive way!

Comment: I don't understand what's really going on here. Did you think I was the one who downvoted this question? I didn't. If that's all about. If not, you need to know that SO is a [collaborative edit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to help improve the site.

Comment: Yes, I thought you edit and downvote it! Sorry for wrong assumtion! Its really annoying getting downvote without knowing the reason, no way I can improve it the next time, its quite useless function then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the line streamReader.Close(); just after else{ it should be fixed..
Anyway, if you really want to close the streamReader, you will have to open the file stream again 
    fileStream = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open);

which of course you might want to let the fileStream as a local variable instead of in using.

Comment: Why I do not see the file being overwrite ? I use fileStream.SetLength(0) to truncate it. But when I open file after running I see both "YES" and "NO" written in different lines. What I want is only "YES" or "NO". Each time should be overwrite every old ones.

Comment: Its fine now, just move that truncate line to the write data section! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/binddecision.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Here is a simplified example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Use file to make binding data decision, 
      //  avoid duplicate binding due to page reload:
      using (var fileStream =
          File.Open("a.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
      {
         // read from the file
         var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
         string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
         if (line == "NO")
         {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
               streamWriter.WriteLine("YES");
               streamWriter.Close();
            }
         }
         else
         {
            // If now is a loop then write NO to the file
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
               streamWriter.WriteLine("NO");
               streamWriter.Close();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```